# why dbeaver puts ""(quotes) to my column name?

Tags: sql, sqlite, dbeaver

I created a table in my SQLite database in DBeaver. When I generate SELECT query:
`SELECT "col1", col2, col3, col4 FROM mytable;`

there is double quotes on my first column name. I directly created it as **col1** and in table view it shows as **col1**. But in SQL query it **"col1"**. There is something that i don't know related to SQLite? col1,3,4 are TEXT by the way.

I rewrite its name in table view but its still same.